# Is the verb "bekochen" oldfashioned?

Tags: grammar, style

If it is oldfashioned, when did it become outdated?

> Morgen werde ich Dich ein philippinisches Essen bekochen.

Comment: your sentence is incorrect. *"dich"* is lowercase and *"bekochen"* stands with Dative and *"mit"* if you want to specify, what is cooked: *"Morgen werde ich dich mit einem philippinischen Essen bekochen"*

Comment: What makes you think it might be old-fashioned?

Comment: The sentence suggested bei Vogel is correct, but I don't understand why you don't want to use the simpler verb "kochen", like in the sentences "Morgen werde ich Dir ein philippinisches Essen (oder Gericht) kochen" or "Morgen werde ich ein philippinisches Gericht fuer Dich kochen." "Bekochen" is not old-fashioned, but is has a different undertone, like in "Seine Oma bekocht ihn."

Comment: "Bekochen" is not oldfashioned, but rather formal and not commonly used with _what_ is going to be cooked. It is almost only used in the following form: "Morgen werde ich dich bekochen" -> Tomorrow I'll cook (big) dinner for you.

Comment: @UwF the only instance where you write addressing pronouns with a majuscle is the formal *"Sie"*...

Comment: @Volker Ok, the context is not specified in the question. But in emails and letters I still use capital letters for Du/Dein/Dir/Dich, etc., and this does not contradict the rules emitted by Duden, it is even their recommendation, see http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/gross-oder-kleinschreibung-von--em-du-du--em--und--em-ihr-ihr--em--1. PS.: I don't think the word "majuscle" exists in English... ;)

Comment: Either "Morgen werde ich dich kochen." (I hope not!) or "Morgen werde ich etwas für dich kochen." or "Morgen werde ich dir etwas kochen." The verb *bekochen*, OTOH, means a habit: "Seine Frau bekocht ihn." means "His wife uses to cook for him."

Comment: off-topic: but majuscule is the word in English

Comment: *Bekochen* is old-fashioned. It’s original meaning is widely replaced by *für jemanden kochen* (e.g. *Unsere Haushälterin kocht für uns.*) When used, it is often used in a pejorative way: *Wird er immer noch von seiner Mutter bekocht?* (weil er immer noch nicht ausgezogen ist)

Comment: To add to @PMF's interpretation: "Morgen werde ich dich bekochen" need not imply that it is a *big* dinner (I guess that's why PMF put that in parentheses), but at least there is a notion of "verwöhnen" involved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no indication at all for the word to be old-fashioned.

[image: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(bekochen%2Bbekocht)%2F(kochen%2Bkocht)&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28bekochen%20%2B%20bekocht%29%20/%20%28kochen%20%2B%20kocht%29%3B%2Cc0]
<sup>[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28bekochen%2bbekocht%29/%28kochen%2bkocht%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,%28bekochen%20%2b%20bekocht%29%20/%20%28kochen%20%2b%20kocht%29;,c0)</sup>

Comment: A comment on this math stuff might be helpful. I'm not sure I got what the graph tells us.